# While Running Airflow using Docker Container on Windows, localhost:8080/ does not load the GUI. Why is it so?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-2.x, vscode-devcontainer

I'm unable to use Airflow GUI because after performing docker-compose up and opening `localhost:8080` in my browser it gives the following error:

[image: Error While accessing airflow gui]

I've faced this error multiple times. Usually the workaround I found is deleting the airflow image and re building my docker file.
Docker File:

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest-python3.9

USER airflow

RUN pip install pandas
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    hostname: postgres_host
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    hostname: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"

  prady1900-airflow:
    build: 
      context: "."
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.7'
    
    volumes:
      - ./airflow:/opt/airflow
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

    command: airflow standalone
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Adding Log Images:
[data log-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfx6X.png)

> **Note:** I suspect installing scikit-learn is causing some issues, just a guess as after adding the RUN command in docker file, airflow started to behave strangely

Can you please suggest a solution?

I tried deleting the airflow image and then rebuilding the docker file. It worked and I was able to reopen the GUI again. But every time I perform docker compose down and the docker compose up I face the same error.

Comment: What do the logs say? Maybe check with `docker logs <name of container>` if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: @Mushroomator Yes, I checked, nothing hinting to the problem Added the logs the problem question for reference